# Compiler for IBM PS/2 Model 30 286

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, cross-compiling, decompiler

I am working on a project that entails developing software for the IBM PS/2 Model 30 286 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_System/2#Models). I am wondering how I might go about compiling programs for this system. I need to be able to render graphics, but I am not sure where to start. Following is a list of ideas of how I might go about doing this. Any thoughts and/or suggestions are welcome.

- Find the source code for a piece of software (ideally a game) that can operate on this machine.
- Decompile an existing program (ideally a game) and pick apart its inner working.
- If I can figure out how to compile C programs, then:

  - Find some documentation on drivers.
  - Figure out whether there is an existing library I can leverage to render graphics.
- If I can find a way to compile programs for this system without having to run a compiler on the system, then:

  - Simulate my program on my PC, then compile my program for the IBM PS/2.

FWIW, I can run DOS on this system. The manual that comes with the computer has no instructions on what program to run for compilation.

Comment: It's going to be hard, if not impossible, to find anything *legally*. Also note that decompilation of an executable file will be unusable as a reference, you might as well read the assembler code directly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is was asked 26 years too late.

Comment: You could try looking for a copy of Borland Turbo C (or Turbo C++). As another commenter mentioned, it's going to be next to impossible to find a copy legally since these softwares haven't been sold for a long time.

Comment: Would the reverse engineering stack exchange be a more appropriate place for this question?

Comment: @Michael, would I compile the program using Borland Turbo C on the actual machine? Also, would writing the program in Basic be an option?

Comment: @baffld: 1) I imagine so.  2) Probably. Depends on what kind of performance you need. I haven't programmed in BASIC in over 15 years so I don't remember which implementations were available that could run on a 286.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOS did not include a compiler, that's why it's not mentioned in the documentation (though PS/2 did have the ROM BASIC). You had to acquire one separately. There were many options available back then, and a few still exist these days. Here's a couple which are more or less usable IMO:

- [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) is a port of GCC to DOS. However, it requires a 80386 so it's not suitable here. It seems there was an attempt to [produce a 16-bit port](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/16bit/) but it was not finished.
- [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/) is a C/C++ compiler which can target 16-bit DOS. You can actually run the tools on your PS/2 box, or cross-compile binaries from Windows or Linux.
- Old versions of Turbo Pascal and Turbo C++ are available from [Embarcadero Software Museum](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/antiquesoftware). These were very good compilers for their day and included a nice text-mode IDE with integrated interactive debugger.
- Quick Basic was a Basic compiler for DOS from Microsoft. It's available on many abandonware sites but I'm not sure about the legality of using it.
- Microsoft Visual C++ 1.52 was the last version of Visual C++ to support 16-bit DOS and Windows programming, and it's apparently still available for MSDN subscribers.

Comment: Along with OpenWatcom and Turbo C, the [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) game programming library is a good way to handle graphics and keyboard/mouse. A version suitable for DOS is still available and somewhat supported.

Comment: amusingly enough mix software still sells power c for the same 20$ it's always been.